# Filling out nav tabs dynamically

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a view with some tabs:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li class="@(item.Well == 1 ? "active" : "")"><a href="#tab-@item.Well" data-toggle="tab">@item.Well</a> </li>
}
</ul>

<div id="tabs" class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-pane active">
        <p>Tab 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-pane">
        <p>Tab 2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-pane">
        <p>Tab 3</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
</script>
```

The tabs themselves work fine, but have this model list: `@model List<WebApplication1.Models.WellModel>` which holds a number of 'Wells'. The view gets the whole model with all the wells in it, so my question is how I can populate the tabs with the data from the correct well. For example, when I click on the tab for "Well 1", it should show me the id, timestamp, image and so on for that particular well. The wells are simply "Well 1", "Well 2", "Well 3" and so on..

Here's the model for the well:

```
    public class WellModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public int Well { get; set; }
        public byte FirstImage { get; set; }
        public byte[] LastImage { get; set; }
        public string TimeStamp { get; set; }
    }
```

Any hints?

UPDATE:

I've added this inside a tab:

```
    <p id="welltab"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("li").click(function() {
            var well = $(this).data("well");
            document.getElementById("welltab").innerText = well;
            console.log(well);
        });
    </script>
```

UPDATE 2:

How do I tell my JS which id to use? Two elements can't have the same id, and writing a function for every element in the tab doesn't sound optimal to me.

These two tabs:

```
<div id="tab-1" class="tab-pane active">
    <h2>Slide ID: </h2>
    <h2 id="wellHeader"></h2>
    <h4 id="wellId"></h4>
</div>
<div id="tab-2" class="tab-pane active">
    <h2>Slide ID: </h2>
    <h2 id="wellHeader"></h2>
    <h4 id="wellId"></h4>
</div>
```

And this Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("li a").click(function() {
    var slide = $(this).data("wellid");
    var well = $(this).data("well");
    document.getElementById("wellHeader").innerText = slide;
    document.getElementById("wellId").innerText = well;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for each, add the data attributes for your properties.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li class="@(item.Well == 1 ? "active" : "")"><a href="#tab-@item.Well" data-toggle="tab" data-wellid="@item.Id" data-well="@item.Well" data-FirstImage="@item.FirstImage">@item.Well</a> </li>
}
```

You can use the attributes of the `clicked li item` when needed

now for getting the attributes

```
$("li a").click(function(){ //add a class check in the selector to make it specific
    var id = $(this).data("id");// access the attributes using the data method.
    var wellId = $(this).data("wellid");
});
```

Comment: Neat. Can you give an example of how I can get the attributes?

Comment: I've tried to add that javascript, but the value doesn't get parsed to it. The console says 'well' is 'undefined'

Comment: @Khaine775 i have updated the  JS code, just check if you can get the values through js functions. :)

Comment: A bonus question, but what would be a good way to differentiate between the different elements in the tab? I can't use the same id more than once, so how do I tell my script which tab to fill with data? Please see the updated OP.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the assumption that you use some kind of library that toggles the respective `div`'s visibility if you click the according `li`, you can print your tabs just as you print the menu:

```
@foreach(var well in Model)
{
    <div id="tab-@well.Well" class="tab-pane @(well.Well == 1 ? "active" : "")">
        <p>Tab @well.Well mister Anderson</p>   
        <p>@well.TimeStamp</p>
        <!-- and so on -->  
    </div>
}
```